# How to share cookie between front-end app and backend server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, fetch-api

In a javascript single page application, on first request of the user to the front-end, a cookie is set with Node JS Express.

Credentials are included to requests by adding the "credentials: include" option to Fetch API.
The first render is server-side with React server side rendering.

I can see the cookie in developer tools. It is sent on every request to the front-end, but not to the backend.

Front-end and backend are both node servers. In development they are on differents ports of localhost, (also tried setting a domain in hosts file but no difference). In staging the api server is on a subdomain of the front-server domain. Neither works.

Can they share the same cookie or should I create one cookie for each? I can't seem to set the cookie for the requests to the backend, either because different port in dev or different subdomain in staging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok so I think I figured it out.

Cookies were sent on some requests but not on others. Checking the request method, turns out cookies are not sent when method type is "OPTIONS", which is preflight, and apparently this is normal.

The workaround is to avoid checking cookies if request method is OPTIONS and just send a 200 empty response in this case, so that the real request can proceed, during which cookies will be sent.